# Does action of $X^{T}y$ project $y$ onto column space of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here below I do not understand why the multiplication of $X^{T}$ on $y$ projects $y$ onto the column space of $X$.

What I have learnt in Linear Algebra, I just know e.g. $Ax = b$, $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Let $p = X \beta$, and observe that $X^T p = X^T y$. Then $X^T (y - p) = 0$, which means that $y - p$ is orthogonal to the column space of $X$ [since the rows of $X^T$ are the columns of $X$]. Moreover, $p$ is in the column space of $X$ [since $p = X \beta$]. Thus, $p$ is the [projection](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf) of $y$ onto the column space of $A$.

Comment: I understand $y-p$ is orthogonal to the column space of $X$ and $p$ is in the column space of $X$. However, I do not know how it relates to the fact that $y$ is projected to the column spaces of $X$.

Comment: That means we can write $y$ as a sum $y = y_1 + y_2$ where $y_1$ is a vector in the column space $\mathcal C(A)$ of $A$, and $y_2$ is a vector in the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $\mathcal C(A)$, usually denoted by $\mathcal C(A)^\perp$ (and therefore $y_1$ and $y_2$ are orthogonal). Here, $y_1 = X \beta$, and then of course, $y_2 = y - X \beta$.

Comment: The point is that $X \beta = y$ may not have any solutions (since the system is overdetermined), so we choose instead to find a solution $\beta$ to $X \beta = y_1$, where $y_1$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $\mathcal C(A)$. This $\beta$ is the least squares (approximate) solution to the overdetermined system. Related to this is the [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#Types_of_generalized_inverses) and in particular, the [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices) of $X$, given by $(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$.

Comment: thanks. Thing is made clear by writing $y = y_1 + y_2$ and $y_1$ is indeed $p$ in your first message. Thanks again.

Comment: I see that the phrasing they have used is confusing. To be clear, $X^T y$ is *not* the projection of $y$ onto the column space of $X$. I don't know why they have written in that confusing manner.